# How to build tab completion for string

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have the following code (taken from https://web.archive.org/web/20190402231844/https://debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2):

```
_foo() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts="--help --verbose --version"

    if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi
}
complete -F _foo foo
```

this works well for autocompletion for the second word:

```
 $ . /etc/bash_completion.d/foo
 $ foo --[TAB]
 --help     --verbose  --version
```

How can I provide tab completion for the first word?

I'm looking to be able to do:

```
$ fo[TAB]
--help     --verbose  --version
```

I couldn't find any information online regarding tab completion for the "same" first word

Comment: At `fo`, bash doesn't even know you're looking for `foo`. For all it knows it could be `four`, `foobaz` or something else altogether.

Comment: @muru that makes sense. But is there a way to achieve same string tab completion?

Comment: Not the way you want it, I'd think. At that point, bash is still trying to complete the word `fo`, not what might follow it, so you'd need to override bash's normal command completion to insert a new word. If it were `fo [TAB]` it's still simple, but this is a bit unusual

Comment: @muru I see. I'm working on a REPL bash program and I'm trying to have it so if the user types certain words, they get certain tab completions available